# Render LI from within a UL in vue.js. Is there an invisible tag?

Tags: vue.js

How can I render an li from within a v-for in vue.

I'm looking to do something like this.

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <span v-for="(item, name) in lineItem.properties" v-html="item"></span>
</ul>
```

But I obviously don't want the **span** to be rendered as item may well be bringing back multiple li's. In my case, item brings returns the li content already rendered into an an li.

Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

you need to use this https://github.com/Thunberg087/vue-fragment#readme

```
<ul class="list-unstyled">
    <fragment v-for="(item, name) in lineItem.properties" v-html="item"></fragment>
</ul>
```

ps if you're using vue 3 you don't even need to install the library, it come out of the box!
https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/new/fragments.html